# Is it better to have one thread for many processes, or one thread for each process?

Tags: python, multithreading

If I have a Python class that runs some processes on the main thread, but wants to run some other processes concurrently, is it better to have each different process run on its own thread, or, if you can, have all of them run in one designated thread?

So, for example...

Is this better:

```
class blabla():

    def __init__():
        pass

    def some_process1(self):
        pass

    def some_process2(self):
        pass

    def some_process3(self):
        pass

    @threading
    def concurrent_process1(self):
        while True:
            pass

    @threading
    def concurrent_process2(self):
        while True:
            pass

    @threading 
    def concurrent_process3(self):
        while True:
            pass
```

Or is this better:

```
class blabla():

    def __init__():
        pass

    def some_process1(self):
        pass

    def some_process2(self):
        pass

    def some_process3(self):
        pass

    @threading
    def thread(self):
        while True:
            self.concurrent_process1() 
            self.concurrent_process2()
            self.concurrent_process3()

    def concurrent_process1(self):
        pass

    def concurrent_process2(self):
        pass

    def concurrent_process3(self):
        pass
```

This may be difficult to determine without the threading function. I have provided the one I am using:

```
def threaded(fn):
    """ Execute a function passed in a seperate thread
        and wrap for class decor style
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        # This try block doesnt end the thread.. i don't know why, it should
        try:
            thread.start()
            #thread.daemon = True
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            thread.stop()
            sys.exit()
        return thread
    return wrapper
```

Note: I realize I typed `@threading` and the function is called `thread()`... woops... just ignore that.

Edit: Does anyone have any advice for my threading function?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by concurrent. Python doesn't really support multi-core use of threads due to the Global Interpreter Lock. If you need to leverage multiple cores, you need to use processes.

Comment: @Beefster. I don't think that's quite right.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, ...depending on the workload, it's not far from right. If you're calling out to a C library that releases the GIL before doing heavy labor (or blocking on I/O, &c), then yes, you can properly multitask using only threads, but if you're doing all your work in native Python, then Beefster's pretty much on point.

Comment: @JohnLexus, ...also, if you're using the word "process" to refer to a chunk of code you want to call, rather than to refer to an OS process (which is the pertinent meaning in the context of discussing parallelism/threading), then the terminology is extremely confusing.

Comment: Regardless, right now, there's simply not enough information to allow a good answer here. We don't know the nature of your code (whether it's CPU- or IO-bound, whether -- if the former -- it holds the GIL), we don't know the nature of your goals (`while True: pass` doesn't really say anything about latency requirements, resource contention, etc), we don't know... *anything*, really, that would allow a usefully contextualized answer.